# jQuery Slide toggle and fade in issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://www.kflap.com/articles.php?id=2

As you can see when clicking on a number, the title fades in alright but the text just appears below instead of sliding into place. When closing however, the text slides back perfectly. I understand this may be a weird technicality due to the fade in and slide toggle being related.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".revealHeader").click(function(){
      $(".revealTitle", this).fadeIn("fast");
      $(this).nextAll(".revealText").first().slideToggle();
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="reveal">
<span class="revealHeader">10. <span class="revealTitle">EXAMPLE</span></span>
<span class="revealText"><img src="EXAMPLE.JPG" /></span>
```

Please be aware I am terrible with jQuery as I stupidly never bothered to learn it properly. (Feel free to tear apart my code.)

Comment: FYI, IDs **must** be unique. You're duplicating at least one named "reveal".

Comment: @j08691 Is that the problem then?

Comment: I don't think so, just a note on your code in general.

Comment: @j08691 thanks man, rookie error :S haha

Comment: Change your `<span class="revealText">` to `<div class="revealText">` tag instead

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what the intended behavior is? Fade-in then slide or slide as it's fading in? Should this be true for both slide up and slide down?

Comment: @Valentin he has issue with the description span appearing suddenly with no slide down effect.

Answer (score 2):

try this... This will execute the slide AFTER the fade is finished.

```
  $(".revealTitle", this).fadeIn("fast", function(){
      $(this).nextAll(".revealText").first().slideToggle();
  });
```

if you really want them both done at the same time, I think you will need to split the content into 2 containers. One for fading and one for scrolling.